# c# How do you access ClientSize within a class

Tags: c#, class

I looked online for this and couldn't find an answer. I'm trying to do a method within a class to test if something is bigger than ClientSize.Height but I have yet to find a way to access the ClientSize outside of my main form. The code of where I want to access the ClientSize is shown below. It is within a class.

```
class Ball
{
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double radius { get; set; }
    public Boolean collisionTest()
    {
        if(Y - radius <= 0)
        {
            ceilingCollide();
            return true;
        }
        if(Y + radius>ClientSize.height)////want to add the ClientSize.Height here as shown
        {

        }
        return false;
    }
```

Is there any way to do this? I know I can do this in the Form, bypassing the problem I'm facing, but I feel like using it in Class is a more convenient solution. Any help with this would be appreciated!

Comment: `public Boolean collisionTest(Size clientSize) {...}`

Comment: Thanks, I guess that would work. Is there any way to get it to automatically call the ClientSize so I don't have to input "ClientSize" whenever I want use it? I realize that's kind of lazy... but...yeah...

Comment: That would lead to spaghetti code.

Comment: @LarsTech why? Something crazy (for this case) like  `Ball` depends on `IClientSizeProvider` injected by DI container via constructor would be quite clear and testable...

Comment: If it is supposed to interact with your Form your class should be enabled to do so. So it could have in the simplest case a property myForm which you set to the form when creating an instance of your ball, maybe even in the constructor.. Don't pu the size there if the form's size can cjhange, though!